# как внедрить кнопку в input?

Tags: html, css, input, button

Есть блок поиска, в котором есть кнопка и инпут для ввода текста.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как внедрить эту самую кнопку в `input` справа. Знаю, что инпуту задается `position: relative`, а самой кнопке `position: absolute`. Но как дальше не могу понять.

Приношу извинения за длинные названия классов.

```css
.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_ {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 400px;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid #878787;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_text {
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #000000;
}

.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_edit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #878787;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 45px 0 20px;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}

.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #B72A20;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.search_result_message {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #159815;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_">
  <div class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search">
    <div class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_text">
      Поиск
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_edit" placeholder="Поиск по блогу">
    <input type="button" class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_button">
    <span class="search_result_message"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так, я думаю.
Адаптируйте только код по себя, если это то,что вам нужно.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/lotus34rus/pen/QWyQZZw)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

input[type='text'] {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 70px;
}

input[type='submit'] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```